# Data types supported by RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying send data types like int, float, bolean etc and also Java Object.
I dont see any examples or implementations for this kind of use cases. Those examples I saw they have only string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

with Rabbitmq you can send a buffer, you can create the buffer as you prefer, for example:

```
byte[] messageBodyBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(yourint).array();
channel.basicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey, null, messageBodyBytes);
```

if you want to send a java class, you can serialize it using JSON format.

Long:

You sholud read the amqp protocol specification here : https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize/deserialize the data you want to send. Perhaps using JSON or XML or some other format that's convenient to your app

Answer (score 0):

You can serialze any Java Object that implements `Serializable` interface.