# RabbitMQ cross platform access issue

Tags: rabbitmq

I am working on rabbitMQ and using the C# .net client, publisher and subscriber components are designed and managed by two different team working on different solutions.

Team 1 designing the publisher sends message of Type A by converting it to byte array.
Team 2 designing the subscriber receives the byte data published by team A and need to convert it to Type A for further processing.

Demo Message Type

```
class Message
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Publishing message to Q";
}
```

So in this scenario, do both teams needs to work on shared "Type A" because if both team maintain the same message type at their end then it does not work.

Does there any possibility to use JSON type message structure to store in RabbitMQ so both the system can use it for cross platform. I searched over the internet and find the RabbitMQ server only stores the bytes.

Also our one of the publisher client is built on Java so how to communication with that as it's using the Java client and manage message payload type at it's own end.

I did not find any good documentation on rabbitMQ for same.

Comment: Why a byte array? Why not JSON?

Comment: @LutzHorn Because as per rabbitMQ specification, it only accepts the byte[] array to store the data.

Comment: Where is this specified? I ue e RabbitMQ to send JSON documents with the content type `application/json`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34200756/9455968 for an example.

Comment: Hi @LutzHorn, the link you have mentioned, it's publishing data using RabbitMQ management plugin web interface. While I am using the RabbitMQ .net client to publish data in the RabbitMQ, this client only exposes the method which works with only byte[]. You may also check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840710/data-types-supported-by-rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

I asked same on rammitMQ .net client GIT forum at as per reply rabbitMQ only works on bytes and we can achieve cross platform access as per below:

"RabbitMQ is not aware of the contents of a message and considers a message to be a set of bytes. This means that you are free to serialize your data in any way you would like. You can set message attributes to indicate the content type and content encoding of the message, and consumers would then use that information to deserialize the message body appropriately.

Note that RabbitMQ does not care what any of the message attributes are and will always treat a message as a byte blob.

In your case, use a .NET JSON library to serialize a class or DTO with your message to JSON. You can use a message header to indicate what class has been serialized. Then, the consuming side can use this information to know how to deserialize the JSON."
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/413